# How to get textbox value in acumatica

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Hello Just new in Development in Acumatica

SO i am trying to get the value of a textbox by an pxaction button click

the value of external link in the image is what i am trying to get

Image 1 :

[image]

Image 2 :

[image: Image2]

public PXAction AddtoLazada;

```
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add image to Lazada")]
protected virtual void addtoLazada()
{          
        UploadFileWithIDSelector getval = new UploadFileWithIDSelector();
        var externalval = getval.ExternalLink.ToString();
}
```

but i am getting object reference not set to an instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `getval.ExternalLink` value is **null**.You get this exception because you call `ToString()` for `null` object

```
    public PXAction<UploadFileWithIDSelector> AddtoLazada;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add image to Lazada")]
    public virtual IEnumerable addtoLazada(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (this.Base.Files.Current != null)
        {
            var externalval = this.Base.Files.Current.ExternalLink;
        }
        return adapter.Get();
    }
```